# How do I keep slide show view to the audience, while I switch to normal and back on my own computer?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010, windows-10-preview

I am about to give a presentation. During the presentation I need to go back to normal view to insert some calculations. However, I do not want to let the audience see this. Can they look at the slide show view, while I make alterations in normal view?

I present on a large external screen, I have to use the dual screen mode (same on mine). But I will use a mentometer software, and need to leave the presentation view only on my laptop to do the calcualtions, and then return to the dual screen to carry on with my presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking here. I assume you are familiar with PowerPoints presentation mode which allows one of your PC's screens to be dedicated to the presentation output while the other can do anything - most times, you keep a smaller copy of the current slide plus presentation notes and the next slide up on screen but you can switch to other applications running using the normal alt-tab.

Are you saying though that the presentation output actually uses 2 screens (one big screen showing up as 2?)

How many screens can you connect to your computer? Could you have another screen to extend your desktop onto? 1 for the presentation, one for presenter view & one for other apps - that should work.